# How do I convert a hypergraph to a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

I have a partitioning algorithm that works only on graphs, but my input is in the form of a hypergraph. Is there any technique that maps a hypergraph to a graph?

Comment: Note that hypergraph is a much, much, much more general concept than graph. Many mathematical structures, such as "topology", can in fact be viewed as special cases of hypergraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace each hyperedge $e$ with a complete graph on the set of vertices in that hyperedge. That is the most natural way.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thanks a lot!

Comment: does this define a bijection between the set of all hypergraphs and the set of all graphs?